# C# Stackexchange Questions API

Tags: discussion, api, questions, c#, api-key

I need to build an web application C# and below is what I'm stuck with

Can I use Stack Exchange's API with Key? Do they have a "hello world" key can be used for learning purpose.
I wish to get the count of response posted for any question on Stack Exchange ... https://api.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API without a key, you'll just have lower limits without it. From [the application registration form](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register):

> Upon registering, you'll be provided an API key which grants your app a much larger per-day request quota than using the API anonymously.